# Can I run two email service on 1 domain?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, g-suite, gmail

Can I run google email service and my web hosting email service on 1 domain?

domain.com <--- on google service (top level domain)

mailman.domain.com <--- on web hosting service (sub domain)

Comment: But this is not the same domain to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can just set up MX records separately for the two, enrolling them both in Google Apps separately.

Answer (score 2):

What fahadsadah said - you contorl this via MX records -but I believe you meant you want the MX for one FQDN to be handled by google, and the other (mailmain.domain.com) to be handled by a services somewhere else - same thing - just separate MX records in DNS (and don't forget the SPF and other records that go along with it to make life easy)